# How to find the next nearest object in turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have my code here. Im Trying to find the nearest point when i click somewhere. So im taking the least distance between the point clicked and all other points. My doubts are: 
a)in line(), why is the least_dist getting a value and not selected_point?
b)any pointers for actually getting my code would be helpful

```
    import turtle
    import math

    #starting turtle
    turtle.ht()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.setup(600,600)
    turtle.penup()


    def draw_dots(dot_row,dot_col):
        global points
        points=[[0 for i in range(5)]for j in range(5)]
        dot_x=-200
        dot_y=-100
        for dots_2 in range(dot_row):
            for dots in range(dot_col):
                points[dots_2][dots]=(dot_x,dot_y)
                #print(points[dots_2][dots])
                turtle.goto(dot_x,dot_y)
                turtle.dot(20,"black")
                dot_x+=100
                if dots==dot_col-1:
                    dot_x=-200
            dot_y+=75
        for k in range(3):  #ignore the next 6 lines cause they are just for verifying
            points[k],points[4-k]=points[4-k],points[k]
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(5):
               print(points[i][j],end=" ")
            print()


    def line(x,y):
        least_dist=500
        for k in range(5):
            for l in range(5):
                if math.sqrt(((points[k][l][0]-x)**2)+(points[k][l][1]-y)**2)<least_dist:
                    print(1)
                    least_dist=math.sqrt(((points[k][l][0]-x)**2)+(points[k][l][1]-y)**2)
                    print(2)
                    selected_point=(points[k][l][0],points[k][l][1])
                    print(3)#im putting "print" here just to ensure that that line is under going #compilation but selected point dosent have a value
                else:
                    selected_point="none"

        print(selected_point,least_dist)



    def clicked(x,y):

        turtle.goto(x,y)
        column=(x+300) // 100
        row=(-y+300) // 75

        print("x:",x,"y:",y,"column",column,"row",row)
        line(x,y)

    turtle.onscreenclick(clicked)
    draw_dots(5,5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is flawed, from the start.  For example, you initialize a list of 25 two dimensional points using:

```
points=[[0 for i in range(5)]for j in range(5)]
```

But that creates a list of 5 five dimensional points!  You want more like:

```
points = [[0, 0] for _ in range(25)]
```

This indexing continues the error:

```
for dots_2 in range(dot_row):
    for dots in range(dot_col):
        points[dots_2][dots]=(dot_x,dot_y)
```

Instead, you need more like:

```
for dots_2 in range(dot_row):
    for dots in range(dot_col):
        points[dots_2 * 5 + dots] = (dot_x, dot_y)
```

Below is my rewrite of your code to get it to work as you describe:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_dots(dot_row, dot_col):
    dot_x, dot_y = -200, -150

    for row in range(dot_row):
        for col in range(dot_col):
            points[row * 5 + col] = (dot_x, dot_y)

            turtle.goto(dot_x, dot_y)
            turtle.dot(20)
            dot_x += 100

            if col == dot_col - 1:
                dot_x = -200

        dot_y += 75

def clicked(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    least_dist = 600
    selected_point = None

    for point in points:

        distance = turtle.distance(point)

        if distance < least_dist:
            least_dist = distance
            selected_point = point

    print(selected_point, least_dist)

    screen.onclick(clicked)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

points = [[0, 0] for _ in range(25)]

draw_dots(5, 5)

screen.onclick(clicked)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time! i have my own explanation of things:1. that 5 dimentional points, i didnt mean it in a 5d way, instead 5 rows and 5 columns in a nested list, and ill put (x,y) in the place of 0.

Comment: Thank You, that was very useful. what i dont understand is the use of "onclick(None)". I just dont get what it does.

Comment: @BARATHVIRUPRIYA, the `onclick(None)` turns off the event handler so that clicks that occur while the `clicked()` function is running are ignored.  This prevents a number of problems.  The event handler is reinstalled on the way out of the function.